# how to define a class that has a method which according to a check box enable or disable some textbox, panel, ect ... in C#

Tags: c#

I have a form whit some text Box and Panel,

I want to define a class whit 3 methods that when a combo box selected Index =0 enable some text box for me, and when selected index = 1 disable some text box an enable some text box,

I know how to do this in main form.cs but to avoid long Codes I want to classified them in separate classes.

thanks a lot for answering...

this is my class:

```html
    namespace Ration_1.Classes.Other
{
    public class CowTypeDefaults
    {
        public void LactationCow()
            {
                 if (CowTypeSelectcomboBox.SelectedIndex == 0 )

                  {
                      textbox1.enabled = true;
                  }
                   
                  if (CowTypeSelectcomboBox.SelectedIndex == 1 )

                  {
                      textbox1.enabled = fals;
                  }
            }
                    
            
        
    }
}
```

error of this code:
1. I can't access to my combobox in this class.

I want to recall this method (ie LactationCow) in load_form and when this method runs according to the combobox index enable or disabe a textbox but I don't know how.

Comment: We're not a code writing service. Please have a go yourself and when you get stuck come back here and ask a question about your code. That's how we can help.

Comment: You are right, ;) tnx,

Comment: You'll need to pass the Textbox and ComboBox to this method, if they're not going to be class members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the function LactationCow needs to have the textBox and the comboBox passed to it.

I'd also like to recommend naming your textBox, it may not be an issue however if down the track you have a dozen textBoxes, all named 1-12, trying to remember which one you're referencing is tricky - even worse if you ever collaborate with someone else!

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I named my textboxes, i renamed it here to simplify my question ;) tnx a lot, have a good time

Comment: can you explain to me how pass textbox and comobox to class ?

Comment: public void LactatingCow()
        {
            Form1 fr = new Form1();
            if (fr.CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
this is a good way or not ??
in form1.designer.cs i made the combobox public.

Comment: In the function paramaters (the '(' and ')' ), make the function take a TextBox. Change the text within the fuction using the now local textBox. An example: 
`code`    public class _test
    {
        public static void txtTest(TextBox toCheck)
        {
            toCheck.Text = "checking";
        }
    }`code`